# How can I change SSRS 2016 Report Server so that it will not show hidden items by default?

Tags: reporting-services

The SSRS 2016 Report Server shows hidden items by default and I have not found a way to change this. There's a reason why the items are hidden. How can I change SSRS 2016 Report Server so that by default hidden items will not be shown?

Comment: Are you in an admin role on the SSRS portal? Have you looked at the portal from a non-admin user account? If so, do the hidden folders/items still show?

Comment: Even with 2016 SP1, the behavior is the same. Even as a non admin user!

Comment: @TarZan did you ever manage to make thenm hidden by default? i find this behavior very strange.

Comment: I have continued to check with each service pack release and have reached out to Microsoft. However, I have not found a solution yet.